# Unity UI TextMeshPro blocks clicks on buttons under it

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a UI prefab with following children hierarchy (top to bottom):
-Button with unit image.
-Misc color overlays.
-TextMeshPro text block - necessary to display status messages on top of the button.

The issue is TextMeshPro prevents clicking on the button (since it's on top of the button).

Is there a setting to resolve this blocking or the only way is to place button on top (at the bottom of hierarchy).

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try and toggle off "Raycast Target" in the settings under the text object (documentation can be found [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.textmeshpro@4.0/manual/TMPObjectUIText.html)).

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much! Worked nicely without need for weird hierarchy structure.